# Java Netty keep open connection to client

Tags: java, webserver, netty, synchronization

I have programmed a netty webserver in java and a simple website with html, css and javascript. The webserver is a webinterface for my discordbot.

My problem:

If someone performs an action in the webinterface, I want to update the website for all users.

For example, if someone clicks on the skip button on the website, I want to the action to effect all users on the site.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement websocket connection on client and server side, and send message from server to all opened connections on some event.

Comment: thanks. can you give me an example to integrate websockets in my java netty webserver and in the webside.

Comment: server side: https://medium.com/@irunika/how-to-write-a-http-websocket-server-using-netty-f3c136adcba9 client side:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

Comment: I have test the Serverside before with the same link but for me it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have an other example for Server side

Comment: example with broadcasting a message received on one channel to all other connected channels: https://leanjava.co/2018/03/14/getting-started-with-netty-building-a-websocket-broadcast-server/